# Linear transformations of a specific characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, characteristic-polynomial

I want to know all linear transformations having the characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$?how can I know their number? how can I know them exactly? Is it by Jordan blocks or what?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: “All” linear transformations? Infinitely many. You should specify the field (real vector spaces? complex vector spaces?) and when you will consider two linear transformations to be “the same”.

Comment: yes, I am speaking about a real vector space. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Actually, I was interested in the $R-$module of order (product of its prime ideals or product of all elementary divisors/ invariant factors) is $(x-1)^3(x + 1)^2$ where we have that $k$ be a field and $R = k[x].$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I also know (from a previous question of mine) that to give a $k[x]$-module is, up to isomorphism, to give a $k$-vector space $V$ together with a linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$ (where the idea is that $x^n$ acts on $V$ by $T^n$ ).are we going to use  Cayley Hamilton theorem somewhere in the answer? If so, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(x-1)^3(x+1)^2$ splits over any field, a matrix with that characteristic polynomial has a Jordan Normal Form over the base field. The linear transformations are hence obtained by conjugating the basic JNF matrices
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
  A & 0 \\
  0 & B
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
A \in \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
\end{align*}
and

\begin{align*}
B \in \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 \\
  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
\end{align*}

If you're interested in the number of these over a finite field, say, you should probably ask a separate and more clear question about that.

Comment: yes I am speaking about a real vector space.

Comment: Actually, I was interested in the $R-$module of order (product of its prime ideals or product of all elementary divisors/ invariant factors) is $(x-1)^3(x + 1)^2$ where we have that $k$ be a field and $R = k[x].$

Comment: I do not see why your $A$ and $B$ take these forms specifically? how did you canculated them? why they contain specifically $1,-1$ only?

Comment: Let me know please if my clarification in the second comment requires me to ask a new question.

Comment: I also know (from a previous question of mine) that to give a $k[x]$-module is, up to isomorphism, to give a $k$-vector space $V$ together with a linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$ (where the idea is that $x^n$ acts on $V$ by $T^n$ ).are we going to use  Cayley Hamilton theorem somewhere in the answer? If so, where?

Comment: @mathmusic Do you know what Jordan Normal Form is? The form of the matrices will be immediately clear if you do. It's easy to look up. As for $k[x]$-modules, you should check that two $k[x]$-modules $V, W$ are isomorphic if and only if we have an invertible $k$-linear $M \colon V \to W$ such that $MTM^{-1} = U$ where $x$ acts on $V$ and $W$ by $T$ and $U$, respectively. You should then check that my answer shows there are at most 6 different $k[x]$-modules of this sort, up to isomorphism. Finally you should check that they're all distinct. If you have trouble, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Here the vector space associated with each linear transformation is $V^5$ over $k$? or I am wrong?

Comment: @mathmusic I do not know what you mean by $V^5$. If you mean $V \times V \times V \times V \times V$, it's not clear what you intend $V$ to be. In any case, the $k[x]$-module associated with one of the above matrices is $V = k^5$, where $x \cdot u = \begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{pmatrix}u$.

Comment: So all the linear transformations $k^5 \rightarrow k^5$? and you last part of your previous comment give me the action of this linear transformation on $V$? I think that makes a complete sense.